# javascript, remove double quotes inside multiple array

Tags: json, looker-studio, deck.js

I am trying to build a custom visual for datastudio, I got it working but there is a step, i can't fix, Datastudio generate a json file like this

```
export const message = {
  "tables": {
    "DEFAULT": [
      {
        "coordinateid": [
          "143.4999336,-34.777302"
        ],
        "colorid": [
          "169,255,169"
        ],
        "sizeid": [
          1
        ]
      },
      {
        "coordinateid": [
          "143.4999358,-34.7773749"
        ],
        "colorid": [
          "169,169,169"
        ],
        "sizeid": [
          1
        ]
      },
      {
```

in deckgl the relevant code is

```
const drawViz = (data) => {
       var data1 = data.tables.DEFAULT;  

    getPosition: d => d.coordinateid,
```

the only way to make it work, is when i remove the quotes from the values inside the array

```
"coordinateid": [
          143.4999336,-34.777302
        ]
```

is there a way either to remove the double quotes between the bracket or a way just to parse the values and ignoring the double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataStudio returns GEO LatLong coordinates as a comma separated string. The correct way to parse this would be the following:

```
var baseCoordinate = "143.4999336,-34.777302";
// Split out the coordinates into multiple strings
var coordinates = baseCoordinate.split(",");
// Turn the strings into floats
var coordinatesAsNumbers = coordinates.map((coord) => parseFloat(coord));
```

This will give you the coordinates as floats in an array, which seems to be the format that deckgl is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

find the answer

basically, change the javascript object to string using  JSON.stringify the using regex to replace the strings then use Json.parese to change it back to an object

```
  var data1 = data.tables.DEFAULT;
  var data2 = JSON.stringify(data1);
  var data3 = data2.replace(/\"]/g, "]");
  var data4 = data3.replace(/\["/g, "[");
  var data4 = JSON.parse(data4);
```